# Filtering a List Using Vue and Checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to filter a list of posts using the userId in checkboxes. I am pulling the data from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and want to then add checkboxes that when checked filter the list by userId. This is what I have currently:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      userIds: ['1', '2', '3'],
      checkedUserIds: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => (this.jobs = response.data))
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJobs() {
      if (!this.checkedUserIds.length)
        return this.jobs
      return this.jobs.filter(job => this.checkedUserIds.includes(job.userId))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="userId in userIds">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedUserIds" v-bind:value="userId" /> {{userId}}
  </div>

  <div v-for="job in filteredJobs">
    <h2>{{ job.title }}</h2>
    <div>{{ job.body }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am stumped on why when I click a checkbox the whole list disappears instead of filtering by the userId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `userIds: ['1', '2', '3'],` is an array of strings not integers. Try `userIds: [1, 2, 3],`

The json file has `userId` as integers. Types to need to be the same for this function to work.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      jobs: [],
      userIds: [1,2,3],
      checkedUserIds: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(response => (this.jobs = response.data))
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJobs() {
      if (!this.checkedUserIds.length)
        return this.jobs
      return this.jobs.filter(job => this.checkedUserIds.includes(job.userId))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="userId in userIds">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedUserIds" v-bind:value="userId" /> {{userId}}
  </div>

  <div v-for="job in filteredJobs">
    <h2>{{ job.title }}</h2>
    <div>{{ job.body }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such I stupid mistake on my part... Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user9664977 Not a problem. Programming languages are becoming more type strict (which is good for less runtime errors)